# Custom Navigation controller in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

Inside this i am creating the custom navigation controller and i have view as storyboard but that view is not loading

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

//create the navigation controller and add the controllers view to the window
_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];

//check if the first viewcontroller eixsts, otherwise create it
if(self.firstViewController == nil)
{
    ViewController *firstView = (ViewController *)[mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView123"];
   // ViewController *firstView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.firstViewController = firstView;
}

//push the first viewcontroller into the navigation view controller stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.firstViewController animated:YES];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: What is your root view controller? Have you set navigation controller as the root?

Comment: You should not need this if you are using storyboard properly.

Answer (score 0):

firs you should set your navigation as `rootviewcontroller` then try something like this.

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboardstoryboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    MyNewViewController *myVC = (MyNewViewController *)[storyboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewCont"];
     self.firstViewController = myVc;
```